Question about Ito's lemma and interest rate model
I am reading Technical Note No.31 of John Hull's book "Options, Furutes, and Other Derivatives". At the beginning, the PDE of a zero-coupon bond price is given by
\begin{equation}
dP(t,T)=rP(t,T)dt+v(t,T)P(t,T)dz
\end{equation}
where $r$ is the short rate, $v(t,T)$ is the volatolity. Then it says that: from Ito's lemma for any $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $T_2>T_1$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d\ln P(t,T_1)= \left[r - \frac{v(t,T_1)^2}{2}\right] dt + v(t,T_1)dz(t)\\
d\ln P(t,T_2)= \left[r - \frac{v(t,T_2)^2}{2}\right] dt + v(t,T_2)dz(t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, according to Ito's lemma,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d\ln P(t,T) &= \left[\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t} + rP\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial P}  + \frac{1}{2}(vP)^2 \frac{\partial^2\ln P}{\partial P^2}\right] dt + vP\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial P} dz(t)\\
& = \left[\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t} + r  - \frac{1}{2}v^2 \right] dt + v dz(t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
My question is why there is no term $\frac{\partial\ln P}{\partial t}$ in John Hull's technical note?

Because $\ln x$ does not directly depend on $t,.$

Thank you for your replying, why zero-coupon bond price $\ln P(t,T)$ does not directly depend on $t$?

$P(t,T)$ depends directly on $t,.$ Ignoring $T$ let's write $X_t=P(t,T),.$ Ito's lemma is about $f(\color{red}{t},X_t),.$ What is that function $f(t,x)$ in your case?

After reading the techinical note, my understand is $f(t,x) = \ln P(t,T)$

We do not have to read a technical note to answer this question. $f(t,x)=\ln P(t,T)$ is obvious nonsense. What do you mean by $x$ on the left hand side?

sorry, I thought that $x = P(t,T)$ and $f(t,x) = \log(x) = \log(P(t,T))$

Ok. Now apply Ito's lemma to this $f.$
